Windows Vista not showing in boot manager bootcamp
My mid-2010 iMac, running High Sierra and OS X Lion, is not booting from the usb of Windows Vista Bootcamp.
I tried Boot Manager but it was not there. I tried EFI boot but it was still not there.
Bootcamp Assistant would not help.  I looked through Google but I couldn't find anything to help.  Now I’m stuck with using Windows 7 while I wait for help.

Is Windows 7 installed on the Mac? If so, why would you want to go backwards in time by installing Vista? Perhaps you could post the output from diskutil list and state which operating systems you what installed on your Mac.

You model Mac does not officially support Vista. The earliest supported Windows is a 32 bit Windows 7 and the latest is a 64 bit Windows 8.1. While the drivers supplied by Apple may be compatible with Windows 10 and 11, the drivers probably would not be compatible with Vista. If you use an unmodified Boot Camp Assistant application to install Windows, then the following needs to be adhered to.

You can only have one version of OS X/macOS installed before installing Windows.
Windows must be installed to BIOS boot.
You must use a Windows installer DVD. This must be a full installer DVD. In other words, the DVD cannot be an upgrade.

Often there are ways around the above restrictions, but your question does not yet have enough information to state what possible ways exist in your case.
If you what to run Vista, then I would suggest using a virtual machine. VirtualBox still provides free software compatiable with both Lion and High Sierra hosts.
